Uploading file to aws s3 using flutter isolate
I am trying to upload videos from flutter to s3. I want to do it using isolate so that the UI does not get stuck. However, I am unable to configure amplify on the isolate.
I tried to run it without cofiguring amplify on isolate (i.e just configuring it on main).
void uploadFileIsolate(List<dynamic> args) async {
    try {
      final rootIsolateToken = args[0] as RootIsolateToken?;
      SendPort responsePort = args[1];
      File file = args[2];
      String file_name = args[3];

      BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.ensureInitialized(rootIsolateToken!);

      final awsFile = AWSFilePlatform.fromFile(file);
      const options = StorageUploadFileOptions(
        accessLevel: StorageAccessLevel.private,
      );

      final uploadResult = await Amplify.Storage.uploadFile(
        localFile: awsFile,
        key: file_name,
        options: options,
        onProgress: (progress) {
          safePrint('Transferred bytes: ${progress.transferredBytes}');
        },
      ).result;
      safePrint('Uploaded file: ${uploadResult.uploadedItem.key}');
      responsePort.send(uploadResult);

    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    } 
}

And calling it on main as:
final p = ReceivePort();
RootIsolateToken? rootIsolateToken = RootIsolateToken.instance;
if (rootIsolateToken == null) {
   print("Cannot get the RootIsolateToken");
   return;
}
Isolate.spawn(uploadFileIsolate, [rootIsolateToken, p.sendPort, File(video.path), filename]);
p.listen((message) {
   print('Message received!');
});

I'm getting the following error:
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(1107)] Unhandled exception:
PluginError {
  "message": "Storage plugin has not been added to Amplify",
  "recoverySuggestion": "Add Storage plugin to Amplify and call configure before calling Storage related APIs"
}
#0      uploadFileIsolate (package:criccenter_ai/amplify_config.dart:113:7)
#1      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:300:17)
#2      _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)

Adding an amplify configuration function gives me the following error:
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(1107)] Unhandled exception:
Unsupported operation: Background isolates do not support setMessageHandler(). Messages from the host platform always go to the root isolate.
#0      uploadFileIsolate (package:criccenter_ai/amplify_config.dart:114:7)

What am I doing wrong?

As the upload function is an async function I don't see any advantage of using an isolate. If you insist of using one, google for using plugins in isolates. But it might be that it is not possible to initialize the AWS plugin inside an Isolate.
